# Onclick href event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use an onclick event to get the value of an href to add it to an input, here's what I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".sellorderprice").click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#buyprice').val($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
  });
  $(".sellorderamount").click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#buyamount').val($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
  });
selldone();
sellupdate();
});

function selldone(){
setTimeout(function(){ sellupdate(); selldone(); },5000);
}
function sellupdate()
{
$.getJSON("<?php echo URL;?>/dashboard/sellorders", function(data){
    $("#sellingorders").find('tbody').empty();
    $.each(data.result, function(){
    $("#sellingorders").find('tbody').append("<tr><td><a href=\"#"+this['price']+"\" class='sellorderprice\'>"+this['price']+"</a></td><td><a href="+this['price']+" class=\"sellorderamount\">"+this['amount']+"</a></td><td>"+this['cost']+"</td></tr>");
    })
});
}
```

the following code, appends data to a table, which works, and I am wrapping the price and an amount in hrefs so I can initiate the sellorderprice click function and the other one. Yet, it doesn't work, it just visits the link.

I have checked my debug console and that doesn't show any errors, my input is correct. Am I ordering the functions in the wrong order? That's only what I can think of.

Comment: Protip: do NOT use `href="..."` if you *do not intend* for the user to go there. Because at the very least webcrawlers will incorrectly index your content (and crawler errors are bad for SEO), and at worst your code won't work and your users end up in weird places (as is happening here).

Comment: Thanks, what do you recommend using instead, to stop that from happening?

Comment: A `data-*` attribute and a `<button type="button">`

Comment: But I only want the text shown rather than an actual button as it would mess the style up.

Comment: You can style a button to look like not a button.

Comment: well, since you are using `.preventDefault`, it shouldn't have problem redirecting the page to somewhere else. Can you post your HTML as well? Does it not even register the click event or just does not read the href attribute? You should put a console log inside of your click events and see if it is actually getting inside of the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way you bind event handlers.

```
$(".sellorderprice").click(function(e){

  });
  $(".sellorderamount").click(function(e){

  });
```

Looking at your code, you're creating these links dynamically and appending to some table. But `click()` only works if your elements are already present in the DOM at the time you're defining these click handlers. So you need to use `on()` (in JQuery 1.7+) in delegated mode like this

```
     /* Assuming sellingorders is a static element, if this is also 
  some dynamically added element, change main selector to closest static 
  parent (or) document if there's none*/

    $("#sellingorders").on('click','.sellorderprice, .sellorderamount',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          if(this.className == 'sellorderprice'){
              $('#buyprice').val($(this).attr('href'));
          }else{
              $('#buyamount').val($(this).attr('href'));
          }
    });
```

Hope this helps :)